# Piping Email with Postfix

Tags: php, email, pipe, postfix-mta

I'm trying to set up a pipe for a specific email address.  I'm following what I see [here](http://support.deskpro.com/manual.php?p=166), but after `newaliases` I get the following:

```
postalias: warning: /etc/postfix/aliases, line 1: name must be local
```

My `/etc/postfix/aliases`:

```
pipe@example.com: "| /usr/bin/php -q /home/path/to/file/pipe.php"
```

When I try sending an email it returns deliverable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: example.com probably does not match your local domain.

Comment: Is example.com in your local hostnames list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Postfix [aliases(5) man page](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html):

> ```
>   o    An alias definition has the form
>             name: value1, value2, ...
> ```
>
> The  name  is a local address (**no domain part**).  Use double quotes when
>   the name contains any special characters such as whitespace, `#',`:',
>   or  `@'.  The  name  is  folded to lowercase, in order to make database
>   lookups case insensitive.

To forward email for arbitrary domain addresses, read about [virtual(5)](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html) instead.